# Multiple labels in chart js, i want to change the order of the labels

Tags: laravel, chart.js

```
   const subLabels = {
        id: 'subLabels',
        afterDatasetsDraw(chart, args, pluginOptions) {
            const { ctx, chartArea: {left, right, top, bottom, width, height}} = chart;
            ctx.save();

            // the problem
            @foreach($categories as $key => $cat)
                subLabelText("{{$cat['title']}}", width / {{count($categories)}}  * {{$key}})
            @endforeach

            function subLabelText(text, x) {
                ctx.font = 'bolder 12px sans-serif';
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.fillText(text, x + left, bottom + 20);
            }
        }
    }
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [
                @foreach($categories as $key => $cat)
                    @foreach($cat['verbatim'] as $verbatim)
                        '{{ $verbatim }}',
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            ],
            datasets: [
                ...
            ]
        },
        plugins: [ChartDataLabels, subLabels],
        options: {
            ...
        }
    });
```

I fetched the categories title from the database order by column 'position' but somehow the function subLabelText() displays it in the order of id in the database.

I did var_dump($categories), it gives the datas in order by 'position'.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

To change the order of the labels in the chart, you'll need to modify the labels property of the data object in the chart configuration.

One approach would be to sort the $categories array in the desired order before generating the labels for the chart. For example, if you want to sort the categories based on the "position" field in ascending order:

```
$categories.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.position - b.position;
});

labels: [
  @foreach($categories as $cat)
    @foreach($cat['verbatim'] as $verbatim)
      '{{ $verbatim }}',
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
],
```